# How does conditional independence cause p(y=1,x) = p(y=1,t=1,x)?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, machine-learning

I am working through problem set 1 for Stanford's CS 229 course, and I'm stuck on what appears to be a simple question on conditional probability.

Here's the question
[image: Here's the question]

*If you don't feel like clicking, we're trying to find *a* s.t. p(t=1|x) = p(y=1|x)/*a*, where y and x are conditionally independent given t*

Using the basic definition of conditional probability, I've been able to do the following:
*note: I'll be omitting "(i)" superscripts*

```
p(t=1|x) = p(t=1,x)/p(x)

Using p(y=1|t=1,x) = p(y=1,t=1,x)/p(t=1,x) 
=== p(t=1,x) = p(y=1,t=1,x)/p(y=1|t=1,x):

p(t=1|x) = p(y=1,t=1,x)/(p(y=1|t=1)*p(x)) **[equation 1]**
```

At this point, I'm not seeing a way to isolate p(y=1|x), so I check *what I believe to be* the answer key. I should probably mention that I am simply following this course via lectures on youtube and I got the problem sets and answer key from somebody's github repo. So far, all answers in the key have matched my own.

Here is the answer according to the key
[image: Here is the answer according to the key]

My issue is with the very first line of this solution

```
The first line states that p(y=1|x) = p(y=1 | t=1, x) * p(t=1 | x)
If you expand each side using the definition of conditional probability, you'll see that this is basically saying:
p(y=1,x) = p(y=1,t=1,x)
```

**I cannot find any way to verify this**

If we assume that this is true and substitute this into **equation 1**, we get:

```
p(t=1|x) = p(y=1,x)/(p(y=1|t=1)*p(x))
= p(y=1|x)/p(y=1|t=1)
This gives us alpha = p(y=1|t=1), which is what they got in the answer key (at least according to their second line. The value they define as alpha seems to have come out of thin air.
```

### **In case it's not clear, I am extremely confused on how they are getting p(y=1,x) = p(y=1,t=1,x)**

In case I'm not considering some critical info, here is the full problem
[image: In case I'm not considering some critical info, here is the full problem]

Comment: Consider typesetting relevant parts of your questions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

> The first line states that $p(y=1|x) = p(y=1 | t=1, x) * p(t=1 | x)$
>
> If you expand each side using the definition of conditional probability, you'll see that this is basically saying:
> $p(y=1,x) = p(y=1,t=1,x)$

Yes.

**Notice:** *All labelled examples are positive.*  $p(t^{(\imath)}=1\mid y^{(\imath)}=1)=1$ .

When given a labelled sample, then it is certain to also be positive. ( For any outcome where $y^{(\imath)}=1$ holds, then too does $t^{(\imath)}=1$. )

Thus the probabilities are equal because they are for the same event.  $p(y^{(\imath)}=1, x^{(\imath)})=p(y^{(\imath)}=1,t^{(\imath)}=1,x^{(\imath)})$